# retrieve the original version of a C++ file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

So I was working with a C++ project. Something wrong happened when I was trying to tar the file. Now when I open the file on Visual Studio Code it shows me this message.

```
The file will not be displayed in the editor because it is either binary, very large or uses an unsupported text encoding
```

It's not only about Visual Studio Code, I can't open the file on any text editor. The extension of the file still `.cpp`

How could I retrieve the original version of the file?!

Comment: Look at the file with a hex editor. What does it contain?

Comment: if on Linux, run: strings filename.

Comment: I got a lot of mix between numbers, symbols and chars

Comment: hundreds of lines of that

Comment: *"when I was trying to tar the file"* -- what command did you run?

Comment: Did you forget to "untar" the archive?

Comment: @axiac tar cvfz submission.tar simple-shell.cpp

Comment: simple-shell is the name of C++ file

Comment: The `tar` command is correct, it does not overwrite `simple-shell.cpp` or create the archive with this name.

Comment: If you have changed a file and want to go back to the previous version, then check out the previous version from your version control system ([git](https://git-scm.com), [mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org), [svn](https://subversion.apache.org) or similar). Not using version control? Start *now*! *Always* use version control, even for trivial projects.

Comment: Always use version control. Git is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you have lost that file (e.g. after a mistake like `gcc foo.cpp -o foo.cpp` e.g. compiling with output into the source code ).

Of course, **you have backups.** Use them.

Then, consider learning how to use some [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system. I strongly recommend [git](http://git-scm.com/) (even for tiny personal projects where you are alone to code), and you then should `git commit` often, typically every hour of work at least (be however sure to commit code which compiles correctly, but could be very buggy).

<sup>(losing some code is a mistake we always did once in our lifes; I am old enough to have lost punched cards....)</sup>

I am not an expert in using `git`, but I do find it invaluable. If you write [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), consider using `git` with your repository on e.g. [github](http://github.com/).

`git` has some excellent [documentation](https://git-scm.com/doc), including short video tutorials. You'll use it on the command line. So I *strongly recommend* **learning a small bit of `git` *today***. What you need for a *personal* small project is really simple (even if you would, like I do, use `git` suboptimally).

Comment: Last time i compiled the file it was fine. I didn't use git because it's small project so i thought i would not need it.

Comment: If you don't use a normal version control like `git`, then write a batch file that zips the source directory into a time-stamped zip file -- that works to in a pinch.

Comment: @David C. Rankin or just use git. It takes 2seconds to do `git init` there's really no excuse for no doing it properly.

Comment: Oh, I'm not knocking git, I love it, but for short file (like answers here), a simple script that copies to a timestamped version of your filename in a /sav directory is fine for those reluctant to dive into git. While `git init` may take a second, branching, merging, discarding branches, rebasing, etc.. tends to take a few minutes more to make friends with.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I'm really a newbie with `git` but for simple personal projects I find it quite easy to use. I don't claim to use it well enough...